# My computer can turn on only when I move ATX cable

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

https://youtube.com/shorts/9bu40A6A0Ic?feature=share

As you see in the video in order to open pc, I need to move and find the true position of atx cable.

-when It is not in true position, once I press the power button it opens for a second and closes. Unless I discharge PSU by plugging out power input cable and pressing power button, it opens and closes again.

-When it is in the true position, the computer work very properly. I can play games as always be for long while even 24 hours. But If I close pc The problem returns and I need to move and find true
... So I return to beginning.

-Instead of closing pc when I sleep pc, I can start computer properly.

I am sure that the problem is either in the Psu or motherboard.

What problem can be?

MOTHERBOARD: MSI X370 GAMING PLUS AM4 AMD Ryzen DDR4 3200+MHa(OC) USB 3.1

PSU:Cooler MasterWatt MWE 750W 60 Plus gold 120MM fan

Comment: If physically shifting/moving the cable makes a different, then the cable is most likley damaged and would need to be replaced.

Comment: Besides a broken wire or a bad connection between a wire and a crimped pin, it could also be a pin that is not properly locked in the connector and therefore not properly connected to the corresponding pin on the mainboard. You could pull out the connector and check if all pins are firmly locked in the body of the connector. A broken or bent pin could also cause a loose contact.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "true position of the cable"? I would agree either others, if moving the cable allows the unit to turn on, you need to **replace** the cable at a minium.  If the behavior is still witnessed after you replace the cable and/or PSU then the problem is the header on the motherboard.

Comment: I mean in true position that the cable's station that allows the computer work.

Answer (score 0):

It is very weird that the power supply ATX connector would go "bad" but the others are correct - pull it from the motherboard and inspect the pins to ensure none are broken/loose or missing and do the same for the ATX port on the motherboard.

Also, as they say, replace the power supply first if you cannot determine where the problem is, power supply is cheaper than motherboard is the logic. Replace cheapest parts first and move towards more expensive parts if necessary when the actual hardware issue is in-determinant.

An easy and cheap way to do this is to use a spare power supply or one from another PC with the same type of motherboard - take the side panels off and disconnect the power cable for the working PC and connect it to your non-working PC (usually the cable is long enough to do this even though you need to place the PC's closed together (I've done it) and press the power button. If it turns on right away (there WILL be errors because none of the other power supply cables are connected to your PC-ignore the errors - this is just a test to see if a known working power supply works on your system) then replace the power supply - if the same symptoms occur then replace the motherboard.

Comment: I think it is very weird too. I am agree with your idea that trying the parts on other working pc. If I had, I would have tried. I brirn the motherboard and PSU to computer guy(I don't know what is called it in English). I will respond  when I learned the issue.